# Generics, classes and instances

Tags: python, python-typing

Is there any concept where I can combine generics and outline a relationship between classes and instances of that class?

A bit of a contrived example, but it get my point across:

```
ManagedClass = TypeVar("ManagedClass")


class MyClass1:
   def my_method(self):
      ...


def instantiate_class(cls: ManagedClass, *args, **kwargs) -> ManagedClass:
    return cls(*args, **kwargs)

myclass1 = instantiate_class(MyClass1)

myclass1.my_method()  # IDE Warning: Parameter 'self' unfulfilled
```

The warning is obviously correct, but not what I am after.

Is there any way to provide this concept to type checkers, where the input type is a class and the return type is an instance of that class?

Comment: You need to annotate `cls` with `typing.Type[ManagedClass]`, currently it isn't correct

Comment: Why not use a `@classmethod` which does exactly what you want - take class name as input and return a class instance?

Comment: @ juanpa.arrivillaga That was quick, and correct!

Comment: @pavel, because this is not my full use case implementation, just an example for a concept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want something like this:

```
def instantiate_class(cls: Type[ManagedClass], *args, **kwargs) -> ManagedClass:
    ...
```

For further illustration:

```
# Type an instance of a class:
foo: Foo = Foo()

# Type a class itself:
foo: Type[Foo] = Foo
```